# Normal to surface of revolution at point.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

> Let $M$ be a surface of revolution given by the parameterization $r: I \times (0,2\pi) \to \mathbb R^3$, $r(t,\theta) = (x(t)\cos\theta,x(t)\sin\theta, z(t))$, and $x(t) \ne 0, z'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t \in I$ ($I$ is an open interval in $\mathbb R$). Show that for any $p \in M$, the normal to $M$ at $p$ intersects the $z$-axis.

I find it hard to think of a way to use the definitions I've seen in class to find the normal to begin with. This is what we covered so far:

1. The normal vector to a k-dimensional smooth manifold at point $p \in M$ is a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ such that for any smooth $\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ we have $\langle v, \gamma'(0) \rangle=0$ .
2. If $M$ is a $n-1$ dimensional smooth manifold given implicitly with $F(x)=0$, then the normal at $p$ is $\nabla F(p)$.
3. If $M$ is the graph of a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^{n-1}\to \mathbb R^n$, then the normal at $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ is the vector $(-\partial_1f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}),\dots,-\partial_{n-1}f(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}), 1)$.
4. The cross product of $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$, $v_1 \times \dots \times v_{n-1}$, is the only vector such that $\langle v_1 \times \dots \times v_{n-1} , w\rangle$ equals the determinant of matrix $A$ with columns $v_1, \dots , v_{n-1}, w$ for all $w \in \mathbb R^n$ as an implication from Riesz representation theorem. In particular, $v_1 \times \dots \times v_{n-1} \in \operatorname{span}(v_1, \dots, v_{n-1})^{\perp}$.

I'm not sure how I can utilize these notions to solve the problem. Also I don't know if this particular case being a surface of revolution and not any surface has any significant meaning to the solution. From previous courses I took I know that in $\mathbb R^3$ the corss product of the partial derivatives of the parameterization does in fact yield a normal vector at a point, but I don't want to use this blindly.

Comment: The partial derivatives in t and $\theta$ gives two tangent vectors, each one perpendicular to the normal vector. When those tangent vectors are not collinear you can determine the normal vector by checking perpendicularity (the dot product to be zero). Then doing the dot product of the normal vector with z-axis which is the vector (0,0,1) should render a nonzero result, proving the two vectors are not parallel. The case when the tangent vectors are collinear ($\sin\theta=0) should be addressed separately.